# Проектирование базы данных " Расписание преподавателя"

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql, запрос

Набросал примерную схему базы данных.Прошу подкорректировать если есть минусы с такой схемы.
И помочь написать запрос на вывод расписания по имени преподавателя.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, в принципе, выглядит нормально. Пара вопросов и замечаний только возникает:

1. В чём разница между "занятием" и "парой"? Можно ли их в 1 таблицу объединить?
2. Почему группа, аудитория, Вид занятия не в таблице занятие?
3. Зачем отдельная таблица для дней недели? Можно же хранить тип дня недели (0-6).
4. Зачем отдельная таблица для номера недели? Его тоже можно в расписании хранить.
5. Лучше изменить названия таблиц на множественные числа Преподаватель -> Преподаватели, Пара -> Пары и т.д.
6. Что значит вывод расписания? В консоль? Или вы используете доп. язык для вызова запроса и получения результатов (php, например)?

Вывод расписания будет каким-то таким для *ваших* таблиц:

```
SELECT * FROM Расписание
JOIN Преподаватель ON Преподаватель.id = Расписание.id_преподавателя
JOIN Номер_недели ON Номер_недели.id = Расписание.id_Номера
JOIN День_недели ON День_недели.id = Расписание.id_Дня
LEFT JOIN Пара ON Пара.id = Расписание.id_пары
LEFT JOIN Занятие ON Занятие.id = Расписание.id_Занятия
WHERE Имя LIKE '%петя%'
```

После `SELECT` я поставил *, чтобы выводить все колонки, вместо неё можете указать нужные вам столбцы. Если учтёте ситуацию в пунктах 3 и 4, то запрос упроститься и не надо будет `JOIN`-ить ещё 2 таблицы.

Обратите внимание, что при отсутствии данных в таблицах `Пара`, `Занятие` столбцы, выбранные из этих таблиц будут со значением `null`. Это произойдет из-за `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Наименования это моя ошибка, эту схему я делал для себя, а наименования в таблице пишу на английском.
1)Занятие - это имеется ввиду какую пару будет вести преподаватель, номер группы и вид занятия
Пара - имеется ввиду какой по счету идет пара 1, 2, 3..., а так же начало и конец пары по времени
2)Занятие обозначает сразу несколько пунктов из-за особенности данных, которые будут вноситься в таблицу

Comment: @Andrey Ну, пока тогда всё нормально. Таблицу номера недели точно можете убрать. Ну, и если пункт 6 - правдив, то можно дни недели, номера пар и их времена в константы вынести и не присоединять лишние таблицы в запросе

Comment: 6)Я использую JAVA  для вызова запроса и получения результата, но основная проблема была в проектировании базы и создании запроса

Comment: @Andrey, был рад помочь

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, если будут вопросы, может спрошу что-нибудь еще